# takes too much time to load report on jsp but not at download Excel(POI)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jsp

I want to get a report on my report.jsp page but it takes too many times and when I download(Excel) this using Apache POI it only takes few secs.

I already tried below code,

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/report")
public String ivrRouteReport(Model model,
@RequestParam(value="startDate", required = false) String startDate,
@RequestParam(value="endDate", required = false) String endDate) {
          model.addAttribute("listReport",serviceInterface.getAllReportResponceBetweenDate(startDate,endDate));
  return "admin/report";
}
```

And Download code is,

```
@RequestMapping(value="/reportDownload", method = {RequestMethod.POST })
public ModelAndView download(Model model,
        @RequestParam(value="startDate", required = false) String startDate,
        @RequestParam(value="endDate", required = false) String endDate
        ) {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("excelReportSummary","reportList", 
                serviceInterface.getAllReportResponceBetweenDate(startDate,endDate));
    return modelAndView;
}
```

Both Controller Methods inherit same DaoImpl method,

```
    @Override
public List<Report> getAllReportResponceBetweenDate(String startDate, String endDate) {
    String strqry= "SELECT c.caller_id_number as caller_id_number, c.destination_number as destination_number,"
            +" c.created_time as created_time, vbDtmf.digit as dtmf FROM VoiceBroadcastDTMF vbDtmf "
            +"LEFT JOIN cdr c ON vbDtmf.uuid=c.orig_id where (c.created_time BETWEEN '"+startDate+"%' AND '"+endDate+"%') ORDER
              BY c.created_time DESC";

    Query query = getSession().createSQLQuery(strqry)
             .addScalar("caller_id_number", new StringType())
             .addScalar("destination_number", new StringType())
             .addScalar("created_time", new StringType())
             .addScalar("dtmf", new StringType())
            .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Report.class));
     List<Report> reportList =(List<Report>) query.getResultList();
     getSession().flush();
    return reportList;
}
```

then why report controller method take too many time to load datas on jsp and Download only take few Minutes? here I am using Mysql and its table have approximate 50K Datas.

Thanks.